# DateFormatter not working Swift with Hour and minute second

Tags: ios, swift, date

Getting nil converting date string to date

```
 func convertDateFormater(dateStr: ""2022-10-22T22:22:16:2216Z"") -> String? {
        
        let inputFormatter = DateFormatter()
        inputFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
        let strSelected = inputFormatter.date(from: dateStr)
}

convertDateFormater(dateStr: "2022-10-23T00:00:00.000Z") // Working fine
***convertDateFormater(dateStr: ""2022-10-22T22:22:16:2216Z"") // Not Working fine getting nil***
```

Should work convertDateFormater(dateStr: ""2022-10-22T22:22:16:2216Z"")

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues in this code

1. `"" … ""` is invalid syntax.
2. There is no parameter type defined.
3. Nothing – or even the wrong type – is returned.
4. `Z` is a format specifier, it must not be wrapped in single quotes.

Apart from that look at your date string. A colon between seconds and milliseconds is very uncommon but it works with this code

```
func convertDateFormater(dateStr: String) -> Date? {
   let inputFormatter = DateFormatter()
   inputFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:SSSZ"
   return inputFormatter.date(from: dateStr)
}

convertDateFormater(dateStr: "2022-10-22T22:22:16:2216Z")
```

But you cannot convert both strings (colon and period separator) with the same date format.

To do so you need a second parameter

```
func convertDateFormater(dateStr: String, hasColonMillisecondSeparator: Bool = false) -> Date? {
    let inputFormatter = DateFormatter()
    inputFormatter.dateFormat = hasColonMillisecondSeparator ? "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:SSSZ" : "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
    return inputFormatter.date(from: dateStr)
}

convertDateFormater(dateStr: "2022-10-23T00:00:00.000Z")
convertDateFormater(dateStr: "2022-10-22T22:22:16:2216Z", hasColonMillisecondSeparator: true)
```